# Eclipse wont recognize my android tablet when I try to test my app?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, usb-debugging

Recently I bought a new android tablet (a no-name Chinese tablet), and I'd like to test an application I'm developing on it.

However, when I try to run it through Eclipse, it won't recognize my tablet (the debugging mode is enabled on the tablet). When I have the select device dialog I see

> Serial Number : ??????????? 
>   AVD Name : N/A 
>   Target : unknown 
>   Debug : 
>   State : ??

I'm running Linux Mint. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, you have to add an udev rule for your tablet. For instance:

```
#cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
```

you can use `lsusb` in order to retrive the vendor id

```
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 0502:3325 Acer, Inc.
```

Answer (score 3):

For Linux you need to setup UDEV to support the manufacture's identity, or you need to restart adb using sudo.

To do it correctly, do this:

```
lsusb
```

and look for your tablet:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
```

Note the ID.

Then go to /etc/udev/rules.d and create a new file called androiddevelopment.rules in that file put this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", OWNER="yyyy", GROUP="zzzz"
```

Where xxxx is the first part of the ID (04e8 in my example), yyyy owner is your username and zzzz is your group.

Then restart udev:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

That should allow Linux to automatically allow your user to connect to that device.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:  How to get Eclipse to recognize my 7" RCA tablet:

This problem frustrated me for two days.  I have a generic RCA 7" tablet that I bought at a Black Friday sale at Walmart.  I was trying to use it with the Android SDK and eclipse, but my computer would not recognize the tablet as anything more than a storage device.  I found several clues that led me in the right direction, but nothing seemed to work; finally found my answer here:
    http://pychildren.blogspot.se/2012/12/getting-android-adb-working-with-pipo.html

(Before you start, if you are as much of a newbie as I am, go to this site first to find out something about terminal commands - 
    community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/100

I was working with Linux Mint 15.  I had also installed the Eclipse and Android sdk bundle.

No matter what I did, Eclipse would not recognize my tablet.  Finally I got the problem resolved.  I really just had to three things:

First I had to go to my home folder

```
Then to the .android folder

    Then add the following line to the bottom of the "adb.usb.ini" file:

        0x2207
```

and save the file.  I was able to do this from the GUI interface.

Second, I had to open a terminal and navigate to the file system folder

```
Then to the etc folder

    Then to the udev folder

        Then to the rules.d folder
```

I had to create a file called

```
"51-adroid.rules" that contained only two lines:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="2207", MODE=="0666"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0x2207", MODE=="0666"
```

(I probably needed only the last line, but several sources had not included the "0x" so I included it both ways.

Then, still in the terminal, I ran the following command from my home folder after the ? (just enter cd to return to the home folder)

```
sudo Development(the name of the folder in which I installed Eclipse and the sdk, yours will be different)/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
```

Then I had to run the following command from the home folder

```
sudo Development(the name of the folder in which I installed Eclipse and the sdk)/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

I also had to make sure that debugging was enabled on my tablet.

I also turned off wifi on my tablet - no one but my last source had mentioned this, but I think that it may have helped.

Then, when I typed in "adb devices", my tablet was recognized.  When I started Eclipse and started the Hello program, it displayed beautifully on my tablet.  I just don't understand why my wife was not impressed.