# Android device in avd not working

Tags: tablet, android

I just bought this cheap android tablet hoping that this will work with android avd for debugging applications.

However I get this ![1]: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38208073/and.png

I am using android tablet [2]: http://www.mytabletpc.pk/buy-p607-apex_flyer_tablet_pc-in-lahore-price

Please help!

Comment: Have you installed the USB drivers of your device..?

Comment: No need to install usb drivers in linux I guess :S

I have been working with samsung glaxy ace without any kind of driver etc

Have you seen the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very clearly answered
For Linux you need to setup UDEV to support the manufacture's identity, or you need to restart adb using sudo.

To do it correctly, do this:

lsusb
and look for your tablet:

Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
Note the ID.

Then go to /etc/udev/rules.d and create a new file called androiddevelopment.rules in that file put this:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", OWNER="yyyy", GROUP="zzzz"
Where xxxx is the first part of the ID (04e8 in my example), yyyy owner is your username and zzzz is your group.

Then restart udev:

sudo service udev restart
That should allow Linux to automatically allow your user to connect to that device.

Reference:
[Eclipse wont recognize my android tablet when I try to test my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312457/eclipse-wont-recognize-my-android-tablet-when-i-try-to-test-my-app)