# how to install my app on my real device,my device is not listed

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just bought Samsung Galaxy S3, and I installed Kies software.
When I tried to install one of my apps from eclipse to my phone I found that my device "Samsung Galaxy S3" is not listed, only the virtual device " the emulator is listed"

How can I have my real device listed to install my app in it.

Comment: Please use this link to see how to switch on the USB Debugging Mode.  http://www.companionlink.com/support/kb/Enable_Android_USB_Debugging_Mode

Answer (score 0):

Firstly opening 'Developer options' then enable 'USB debugging', or you can use adb tool to check if your devices has been attached. Hopes it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled USB Debugging?

```
Enable USB debugging on your device.

 -- On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under 
Settings > Applications > Development.
On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.

-- Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. 
To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times.
Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.
```

For more information go through this [developer's website](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

If you are on ***linux*** then

Very clearly answered For Linux you need to setup UDEV to support the manufacture's identity, or you need to restart adb using sudo.

To do it correctly, do this:

```
lsusb
```

and look for your tablet:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Note the ID.
```

Then go to

```
/etc/udev/rules.d
```

and create a new file called androiddevelopment.rules in that file put this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", OWNER="yyyy", GROUP="zzzz"
```

Where xxxx is the first part of the ID (04e8 in my example), yyyy owner is your username and zzzz is your group.

Then restart udev:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

That should allow Linux to automatically allow your user to connect to that device.

Got this answer from [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187189/android-device-in-avd-not-working?rq=1).