# Eclipse wont recognize my tablet when I try to test my app?

Tags: android, tablet, eclipse-adt, usb-debugging

> Recently I bought a new android tablet (a no-name Chinese tablet), and
>   I'd like to test an application I'm developing on it.
>
> However, when I try to run it through Eclipse, it won't recognize my
>   tablet (the debugging mode is enabled on the tablet). When I have the
>   select device dialog I see

Same thing, however that solution did not help, the eclipse is still cannot see the tablet properly:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzH4F.png

Using ubuntu 12.04
Ment that question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312457/eclipse-wont-recognize-my-android-tablet-when-i-try-to-test-my-app)
Help would be appreciated.
Also, looked at numerous guides, which did not help.

Comment: I think you need to install it's usb driver. Have you tried it in Windows?

Comment: Windows is not available nor appropriate right now.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312457/eclipse-wont-recognize-my-android-tablet-when-i-try-to-test-my-app   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824531/eclipse-doesnt-recognize-my-android-device

Comment: did you read the question properly?